# Possible to have different requirements in django app than parent?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to contribute to a project where is using some older package versions don't meet the minimum version requirements for the packages I need to use. Specifically, I need to use Channels which has a minimum Django requirement of 1.11, but the project is running on v1.8.

I was told by the project lead that it's possible to have different requirements for different versions of packages in your apps by specifying them in your requirements.txt file, but I can't find any instructions online about how to achieve such a thing (I'm new to Django so learning as I go on this project). From what I understand the requirements.txt file is generated from the freeze command, so I would need to install these packages before I do that, in which case would I need to have nested virtual environments?

I can see how this would be possible were I developing in a vacuum, but I need this app to exist in the context of the larger application. I will be using the existing database and visual styles and so need this to reference aspects of the existing site.

I played around with upping the minimum version of Django for the base site, but it deprecated some things the project was making heavy use of, so that's not going to be a solution for me.

Thank you,

Comment: It's not possible. Your app will be running in the same virtualenv as the main project.

Comment: 1.8 hasn't been supported at all [since the beginning of April](https://www.djangoproject.com/download/)... honestly, if the maintainers have no intention of upgrading, I'd either fork it and upgrade if you actually need to use it (1.11 is supported until at least April 2020) or find another project to contribute to.

Comment: This is a bit of a tangent but I don't think upgrading from 1.8 to 1.11 would be such a big deal. I have personally upgraded pre-1.9 projects to 2.x only with a moderate effort.

Comment: Thanks for the comments everybody, it looks like I'll either need to convince them to upgrade or develop this separately from the main project.